# Does a universal (fat) library increase app package size?

Tags: ios

I'm curious if building against a universal (fat) library containing both armv7 and i386 code (for the simulator) increase the size of the apps distribution package or will the build process for the device strip out the i386 stuff and debug information?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I am not mistaken, the i386 is stripped, but for the debug information you can chose if you want it or not:

[image]

Comment: By the way, those are the default values. `NO`for Debug and `YES` for release.